# How do i copy snaphsot of one RDS instance to another?

Tags: amazon-rds, snapshot

We are in the process of creating new RDS instances with the encryption option enabled. Once new RDS instances are created, we need that to have same data as old ones. We have daily snapshots on all of our RDS instances. Is there a way to copy this RDS snapshot to newly created RDS instance?
One option for me is to take mysqldump of each database in old RDS instance and add it to individual databases in new RDS instance. This is time consuming as each database snapshot comes to 40-50 GB. 
Please let me know if there is any easy way to copy that snapshot and put it on new RDS.

Answer (score 3):

An Amazon RDS snapshot contains a complete copy of the data in your RDS instance.

The snapshot can be used to create a *new Amazon RDS instance*. It will then contain a complete copy of the data from the snapshot. However, note that this process **creates a new Amazon RDS instance**. It cannot be used to "insert" the data into an existing Amazon RDS instance.

See: [Restoring From a DB Snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html)

Comment: as per the limitations mentioned in  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html, "You cannot restore an unencrypted backup or snapshot to an encrypted DB instance."

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to configure RDS snapshots into a new RDS instance. Assuming that your RDS configuration is the same for both instances and preferably the same region, You can try to launch a new RDS DB onto your second account (instance).

Depending on the configuration and If your RDS Instance is publicly accessible:

- Install the appropriate DB management tools onto a PC, and give this PC network access to both RDS instances (security groups and DB user access for read and write)
- Using the database management tools to copy the data from one DB to the other DB

(or) Copy data through an EC2 instance as an intermediary:

- Launch an EC2 instance configured with appropriate DB server software
  Copy the RDS DB Data from your RDS instance up to your EC2 instance
- Then launch your new RDS instance into the second account
  Configure appropriate access (security groups and DB user access for read and write)
  Copy the database data from your EC2 instance to your newly created RDS instance

If the RDS instance and the EC2 instance are in the same availability zone, try passing a bash script to the (linux AMI) EC2 instance as user-data, and the details of data transfer can be handled in the script.

Links to refer: 
[Copying a DB snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html),
[RDS Copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/CLIReference-cmd-CopyDBSnapshot.html).

Comment: I think there is no way to directly put the snapshot of existing RDS instance to the new one created. It is mentioned as one of the limitations in - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html "You cannot restore an unencrypted backup or snapshot to an encrypted DB instance."